# Storyboard UITableView not showing static content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I have an UITableViewController with Content property set to Static Cells, I didn't override any method related to data source, I just have some simple Labels in the static cells, but when view loads it' empty!

One important thing I'm pushing from another controller to this controller with following method:

```
 TransactionDetailViewController* appTransactionDetailsView = [[TransactionDetailViewController alloc] init];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:appTransactionDetailsView animated:YES];
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have created the static cells in Storyboard, you could try instantiating it from there. You're simply instantiating the class (`.h / .m`), and not what you made in Storyboard.

In storyboard, give the `TransactionDetailViewController` a **Storyboard ID** in the **Identity Inspector**, I.E `transactionDetail`.

[image: Illustration of Identity Inspector]

Then replace your code with this:

```
TransactionDetailViewController *appTransactionDetailsView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"transactionDetail"];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:appTransactionDetailsView animated:YES];
```

Comment: Great that worked but just a small point using self.storyboard was nil so I had to use this code:

     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                @"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    

    TransactionDetailViewController* appTransactionDetailsView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"transactionDetails"];
        
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:appTransactionDetailsView animated:YES];

Answer (score 1):

Your creating an instance of a viewController, where as in the storyboard you have defined the UI. Either use a segue in the storyboard with:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@" <segueName> " sender:self];
```

or give the viewController a storyboardID and use:

```
MenuTableViewController *mtvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:mtvc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use alloc-init here, basically you need to access your UIViewController via UIStoryboardSegue - just hold ctrl start dragging from your source view controller into destination, release left button and select push or modal. Name it somehow (myItemDetails)

after that just do on event handler in your source vc

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myItemDetails" sender:self];
```

or second (no segue) option in your source vc:

```
UIViewController *detailsVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsVC];
```

to use second option do not forget to set StoryboardID in your storyboard editor to destination view controller